# Let points $A(x,y)$ and $B(x + 1,y)$ be points in an $(m + 1)*(n + 1)$ lattice starting at $O(0,0)$ and ending at $P(m,n)$.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, combinations, integer-lattices, path-connected

So here is the Question :-

Let points $A(x,y)$ and $B(x + 1,y)$ be points in an $(m + 1)*(n + 1)$
lattice starting at $O(0,0)$ and ending at $P(m,n)$. Show that the number
of shortest paths from $O$ to $P$ passing through $AB$ is ${x + y}\choose{x}$${(m - x - 1)+(n - y)}\choose{m - x - 1}$ .

While reading the problem I understood the meaning of it . But I absolutely have no idea of how to prove the fact that it is always ${x + y}\choose{x}$${(m - x - 1)+(n - y)}\choose{m - x - 1}$ . Can anyone help me do it?

Any hints and suggestions for this problem will be greatly appreciated .

Comment: How many paths are there from $O$ to $A$? How many from $B$ to $P$?

Comment: Good hint @BrianM.Scott. The two binomial coefficients are literally those two quantities multiplied together. When you need a shortest path, what things are you free to choose? At each step, you have to either go up or go right. Overall, you have to arrange those UP’s and RIGHT’s into a sequence of moves. Now can you see why you need the binomial coefficient?

Comment: Oh okay ! , so no. of paths from $O$ to $A$ is $\frac{(x + y)!}{x!y!}$ and from $B$ to $P$ we have $\frac{(m + n + 1 - (x + y))!}{(m - (x + 1))!(n - y)!}$ , I guess it's proved now?

Comment: I think for your second quantity, you forgot that you should start from B (not from A). Hence, there should be one less RIGHT move. This fixes the result.

Comment: yes @BenjaminWang it should be (m - x - 1) , edited it right now .